# Use custom datetime format in view (both created in code)

Tags: views, datetime

I have a view displaying a date field (from the Date module). I only want it to show hh:mm though, so I created a new datetime format.
This worked fine until I moved it into my module, i.e. I create it via hook_data_format_types and hook_date_formats. The view is also created by the module (via Features).

Now my problem is that after enabling the module, the view uses the default datetime format.
After saving the date/time formats (without performing any modifications) it works fine though so it smells like some caching issue.

I wonder how to make it work without this step as having to do *anything* but enabling the module, especially when unrelated to what the module does, is not very user-friendly.